# Logback messages being appended to archive file

Tags: java, weblogic, logback

I have a Java Web application running on WLS 12 and using a logback RollingFileAppender to log data. Although it's inconsistent, I will occasionally see the current logging output being directed to one of the archive files created by the rollover process. For example, with the configuration below, I see current logging output being appended to debug.2019-01-17.0.txt instead of to main.log. Am I misunderstanding the expected behavior of the RollingFileAppender? If not, does anyone have an idea about what may be causing the behavior?

```
<appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <file>${LOG-PATH}/main.log</file>

  <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
    <Pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%5p] [%t] \(%F:%M:%L\) %m%n</Pattern>
  </encoder>

  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${LOG-PATH}/debug.%d.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
    <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
    <maxHistory>45</maxHistory>
    <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
  </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Comment: I have the same problem on WLS 12, with almost the same config. Did you get to solve this?

Comment: We recently have witnessed this behavior as well. Did you ever solve this?